# Feature Hashing of zip codes with Scikit in machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, hash, feature-extraction

I am working on a machine learning problem, where I have a lot of zipcodes (~8k unique values) in my data set. Thus I decided to hash the values into a smaller feature space instead of using something like OHE.

The problem I encountered was a very small percentage (20%) of unique rows in my hash, which basically means from my understanding, that I have a lot of duplicates/collisions. Even though I increased the features in my hash table to ~200, I never got more than 20% of unique values. This does not make sense to me, since with a growing number of columns in my hash, more unique combinations should be possible

I used the following code to hash my zip codes with scikit and calculate the collisions based on unique vales in the last array:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction import FeatureHasher

D = pd.unique(Daten["PLZ"])

print("Zipcode Data:", D,"\nZipcode Shape:", D.shape)

h = FeatureHasher(n_features=2**5, input_type="string")
f = h.transform(D)
f = f.toarray()

print("Feature Array:\n",f ,"\nFeature Shape:", f.shape)

unq = np.unique(f, axis=0)

print("Unique values:\n",unq,"\nUnique Shape:",unq.shape)
print("Percentage of unique values in hash array:",unq.shape[0]/f.shape[0]*100)
```

For Output I received:

```
Zipcode Data: ['86916' '01445' '37671' ... '82387' '83565' '83550'] 
Zipcode Shape: (8158,)
Feature Array:
 [[ 2.  1.  0. ...  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0. -1.  0. ...  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  0. ...  0.  0.  0.]
 ...
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  0. ...  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0. -1.  0. ...  0.  0.  0.]] 
Feature Shape: (8158, 32)
Unique values:
 [[ 0. -3.  0. ...  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0. -2.  0. ...  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0. -2.  0. ...  0.  0.  0.]
 ...
 [ 4.  0.  0. ...  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 4.  0.  0. ...  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 4.  0.  0. ...  0.  0.  0.]] 
Unique Shape: (1707, 32)
Percentage of unique values in hash array: 20.9242461387595
```

Any help and insights are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That very first `2` in the transformed data should be a clue.  I think you'll also find that many of the columns are all-zero.

From [the documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.FeatureHasher.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.FeatureHasher.transform),

> Each sample must be iterable...

So the hasher is treating the zip code `'86916'` as the *collection* of elements `8`, `6`, `9`, `1`, `6`, and you only get ten nonzero columns (the first column presumably being the `6`, which appears twice, as noted at the beginning).  You should be able to rectify this by reshaping the input to be 2-dimensional.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I reshaped the Input like this: D = np.reshape(D,(len(D),1)) to (8158,1). However I had to raise n_features up to 4096 to get a unique hash value of 63%. At this point I am asking myself why feature hashing even exists if it has that many collisions, would a binary encoder not be much better?

Comment: With 4096 new columns, and alternating signs, with ~8000 original values you have just about the right amount of space, but the (pseudo-)randomness of the hash means you should expect about 1/e~=27% collisions, which very nearly matches what you observe.  The point of a hash over onehot is that it's much faster to encode  (you don't have to lookup the zip code in the category list every time, you just throw it into the hash function) and more memory-efficient (you don't need to save all the unique zip codes).

Comment: Okay but why even use that? I could easily encode ALL 8000 unique values in 13 bits or 13 columns. That way there would be no collisions at all and instead of 4096 new features I would only have 13? I just can' t think of a case where categorical encoding should favor hashing or am I missing something?

Comment: The last sentence of my other comment gives the reason to use hashing: it's not modeling-ideal, but it is computationally-helpful.  As for a compact binary encoding, that's not great from a modeling perspective; see e.g. https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/54423/55122.

Comment: I guess you could say that yes. The question which remains is at which point binary encoding outperforms hashing and vice versa. Since both add false relationships it's really hard to say but with so many collisions in this case I would go with binary encoding I guess. Unfortunately there is not a lot of research about this topic.